# как правильно привязать TextField к полю?

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, java-8

Пытаюсь создать класс в котором есть связанные между собой текстовое поле и поле с числом, но при попытке связать их через лямбда-выражение выводит сообщение о том что поле должно быть финальным или эффективно финальным.

```
class Stranica{
    private final int[][] kolichestvo = new int[24][4];
    private TextField[][] tfPolVvod = new TextField[24][4];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                TextField tf = new TextField();
                tf.setPrefWidth(50);
                tf.setOnKeyReleased(pdj ->{
                    if(!tf.getText().matches("\\d+")){
                        tf.setText("0");
                        tf.selectAll();
                    //в следующей строке будет ругаться на то что поле не финальное
                    }else kolichestvo[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
                });
                tfPolVvod[i][j]=tf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите как их правильно связать.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить перед инициализаией полей kolichestvo и tfPolVvod  слово final

Comment: @Werder пробовал, та же ошибка.

Comment: Не могли бы вы сказать какие условие вам поставили для реализации? Лямбду вам следовало бы вынести ЗА цикл в другой метод и потом передавать в неё значения.

Comment: @OlegGrechishkin описал ниже под первым ответом, если мой код можно улучшить, подскажите как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так решаются такие вопросы:

```
class Stranica {
    private final int[][] kolichestvo = new int[24][4];
    private TextField[][] tfPolVvod = new TextField[24][4];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                 final int ii =i;
                 final int jj =j;

                TextField tf = new TextField();
                tf.setPrefWidth(50);
                tf.setOnKeyReleased(pdj ->{
                    if(!tf.getText().matches("\\d+")){
                        tf.setText("0");
                        tf.selectAll();
                    }else kolichestvo[ii][jj]=Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
                });
                tfPolVvod[i][j]=tf;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но для справки что-то с этой частью кода явно не так...

Comment: Нужен класс в котором бы был массив цифр, и текстовые поля св,язангые с этим массивом, при введении цифры в поле она автоматически записывается в нужный слот массива. А можно как-нибудь проще это реализовать?

Comment: Если все условия известные мне являются константными то именно **проще** реализовывать некуда. Но вот с точки зрения поддержки,расширения и иных жизненных ситуаций связанных с Вашим кодом тут море нереализованных возможностей.